# SQL Execute in Groovy not waiting until it's done before returning

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy

My code is basically:

```
if (sql.execute('insert into myTable values (value1, value2, ...)') == true) {
   run some other sql query doing analysis on myTable
}
else {
   print "failure"
}
```

Strangely, my statement is returning instantly and printing "failure".  However, I'm watching the table and the insert IS working correctly.

What I'd really like to happen is that after execute is done inserting rows, it then runs the other query inside the `if` block.  What's happening/how can I do this?

Comment: It looks to me like you have your execution out of order.  Can't you just run `sql.execute()` and then run the `insert`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  The thing its executing is the insert statement. Could you show me in code?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood then... you want `sql.execute()` to run first, right?  That being said, do you mean that the code within the `{ }` isn't executing?

Comment: I want to run the command inside the if block after my "execute" statement is done inserting rows.  I don't want it to still be inserting rows when the statement inside the if block runs.

Comment: If the insert is working as expected, the `if` will return `true` based on what you have shown.  Have you confirmed this?

Comment: Brian, good call.  Just checked and it is in fact immediately printing `failure` despite the fact that the insert IS actually working.  Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: I think you should run the insert first, THEN check the database to see that it has been updated and then run the other queries after confirming the DB is updated.

Answer (score 2):

`execute` returns true only if the first result is a `ResultSet`, false otherwise.

In case of an insert, I highly doubt you would be able to check the boolean return.

**Solution:**
Go with [executeInsert](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeInsert%28java.lang.String%29) and use Groovy truth

```
if(sql.executeInsert('insert into myTable values (value1, value2, ...)')){
....
} else {
 ....
}
```